# Evaluating p && *p++

Tags: c, pointers, logical-operators

I was reading this can be inferred as short form of

```
if (p) { 
 *p++;
}
```

but not quite understanding the logic behind it.

My understanding is if p is false then the operator results in 0 regardless, but if p is any other value then *p++ can be evaluated, is the second portion dereferencing the value in the address pointed at p and incrementing that by 1?

Edit: Further note, this was said to prevent null pointer access where a null pointer = 0x00000000.

Comment: @Diante  This code snippet  if (p) { 
 *p++;
} does not make sense. The value of the dereferenced pointer is not used.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: If `p` is a pointer to volatile, it *is* used, isn't it?

Comment: @KerrekSB Where is it used?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Hm, maybe I'm confusing it with C++. In C++ this would necessitate an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, but perhaps it does not so in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was reading this can be inferred as short form of
>
> ```
> if (p) {
>   *p++;
> }
> ```

It's more a short form of

```
if ( !p )            // if p is NULL, *p++ is not evaluated at all,
{                    // p && *p++ evaluates to 0
  return 0;
}
else                 // if p is not NULL, *p++ is evaluated
{                    // p && *p++ evaluates to 1 if *p is not 0
  int x = 0;         // p is advanced regardless of value of *p
  if ( *p )          
    x = 1;           
  p++;
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember, operator `&&` is lazy: as soon as it sees an argument is false, it doesn't evaluate the other argument. Thus, the line

```
p && *p++
```

first checks if `p` is non-NULL. If it is, it then evaluates the next operand: `*p++`, and checks if it's not equal to zero. But here's the thing: if `p` were true, then `*p++` will, by definition, be executed.

It may help to add in those `!= NULL` and `!= 0` parts

```
p != NULL && *p++ != 0
```

However, this kind of code is not recommended. It is hard to read.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think this is what the author was trying to get at as it also stated the logic is to prevent null pointer access (apologies I just included this in my edit to my post above).

Answer (score 1):

Close. If p != 0 (and thus presumed to be valid), the block is run.  In the block, the pointer p is dereferenced (a value is fetched from memory), the value is thrown away, and p is incremented by the size of whatever p is declared to point to.

(*p)++ would have incremented what p points to.